# Retornar valores de formulario que se ha llenado previamente - CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

Si se llena un formulario y se le da clic al botón siguiente pero el usuario se dio cuenta que existe un error **y le hace clic a un botón de anterior**, **como hacer para que al momento de hacer clic en el botón anterior me retorne el formulario que se había llenado previamente** y que los campos de dicho formulario aparezcan llenos con el ultimo registro que se había ingresado, y evitar con esto que se tenga que volver a llenar el formulario completamente y solo se tenga que corregir lo requerido.

CONTROLADOR

```
public function carga_vista_anterior_1(){
$data['necesidades'] = $this->Servicios_model->get_ultima_necesidad($id_necesidad);

        $resultado = $this->load->view('servicios/create_update_1',$data, TRUE);

        $response = array('mensaje' => $resultado);



        $this->output
        ->set_status_header(200)
        ->set_content_type('application/json', 'utf-8')
        ->set_output(json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES))
        ->_display();
        exit;
        }
```

MODELO

```
//trae el id mayor de la tabla de necesidad
        public function get_ultima_necesidad($id_necesidad) {

            $necesidades = $this->db->query('SELECT num_necesidad, descripcion_necesidad, tipos_necesidad_id_tipo_necesidad FROM necesidades WHERE id_necesidad in (select MAX(id_necesidad) from necesidades )');

         return $necesidades->result_array();
    }
```

FUNCION JavaScript PARA EL BOTON 'ANTERIOR'

```
$("#anterior_2").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
               method: "POST",
               url: base_url+"/servicios/carga_vista_anterior_1",
               data: $("#frm_create_servicio").serialize(), // Adjuntar los campos del formulario enviado.
               dataType: 'json',
               success: function(data) {
                $('#principal').html(data.mensaje);



            },



            error: function(error) {
                $('#contenido').html('<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">'+
                   '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'+
                   '<stro  ng>Error!!!</strong> Solicitud de AJAX no completada->'+error.status+'</div>'); 
            }
        });
        return false;        
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa Js o Jquery guardas los valores en session Storage, cuando envies el formulario guardas esa información, si vuelve a cargar la pagina en el JS consulta si existe esa info, de ser asi lo cargas en cada uno de los campos correspondientes.

Comment: Como podría implementarlo, podrías darme un pequeño script o referencia? No logro obtener los datos del local Storage, no se si los estoy almacenando bien.

Comment: envia el scritp que estas usando para almacenarlo